# lmer: number of grouping levels < number of observations

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, random-effects-model

> Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations

This is a common error when using the lme4 package, and there are a number of questions about it on cross validated and elsewhere. The same error happens in different contexts.

Here is a minimal example that illustrates my case. I am new to R, so probably there is a very obvous error. However at the moment I do not know what the error message means, so no idea how to correct it.

The minimal example: we would like to see if the mean height of humans (category H), dogs (D), and cats (C) is significantly different.  We obtain the height of 2 humans, 3 dogs, and 2 cats.  In the actual experiment, these numbers would be much larger, and would be the same for each group.

The R model is

```
model = lmer(Height ~ Category + (1|Id), data = Data, REML=TRUE)
```

where the +(1|Id) reflects the fact that the particular humans (or dogs, or cats) chosen
are a random sample from a population.

Here is the code that produces the error:

```
library(lme4)
Category = c("H","H", "D","D","D", "C","C")
Id = c("human_a","humanb",  "dog1","dog2","dog33",  "cat1","cat99")
Height = c(160.,180.,   40., 25., 15.,  15.,20.)    # height in cm
Data = data.frame(Category, Id, Height)
model = lmer(Height ~ Category + (1|Id), data = Data, REML=TRUE)
anova(model)


Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations
Traceback:

1. lmer(Activation ~ factor(Category) + (1 | Image_var), data = Data, 
 .     REML = TRUE)
```

Thank you for any guidance

Comment: If you have 1 observation per Id, then you cannot, and don't need to, use `(1|Id)`.

Comment: This is an error which I have recently experienced. I was just about to post when I came across yours. I am baffled as syntax looks fine, and the number of levels of the grouping factor is definitely less than the number of observations.

Comment: P.S. dropping the random effects term as suggested by amoeba doesn't seem to help.

Comment: the (1|Id) is intended to denote the random effect, that the particular humans/dogs/cats are random samples from the population.  If (1|Id) is wrong, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: The model works as follows: model = lm(Height ~ Category, data = Data). I guess that when we have a between-subjects variable, with one observation per subject, the random effects term is redundant and does not need to be calculated. lme4 is only designed to work with a non-redundant random effects term.

Comment: Or in other words, if there is only one observation per level of the random effect, don't use lmer, and don't model the random effect.

Comment: Thank you. The error message makes sense then. But then, how can one specify the random effect that the 2 humans are sampled from the population of humans?

Comment: This may be a subject for a different question. If you think so, you could say what you did as the official answer for this question.